# Get tick break positions in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have created a function for creating a barchart using `ggplot`.

In my figure I want to overlay the plot with white horizontal bars at the position of the tick marks like in the plot below

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
# By inspection I found the y-tick postions to be c(50,100,150)
p + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = seq(50,150,50)), colour = 'white')
```

[image: irisplot]

However, I would like to be able to change the data, so I can't use static positions for the lines like in the example. For example I might change `Sepal.With` to `Sepal.Height` in the example above.

Can you tell me how to:

1. get the tick positions from my ggplot; or
2. get the function that `ggplot` uses for tick positions so that I can use this to position my lines.

so I can do something like

```
tickpositions <- ggplot_tickpostion_fun(iris$Sepal.Width)
p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = tickpositions) +
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = tickpositions), colour = 'white')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A possible solution for (1) is to use `ggplot_build` to grab the content of the plot object. `ggplot_build` results in "[...] a panel object, which contain all information about [...] breaks".

```
ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$y.major_source
# [1]   0  50 100 150
```

---

See edit for pre-`ggplot2 2.2.0` alternative.

Comment: With ggplot version 2.2.1.9000, this solution doesn't appear to work. It is returning NULL

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @Mikey Harper! The `ggplot` machinery is indeed evolving. I'll have a look when time allows. Cheers .

Comment: With ggplot version 3.3.5 doesn't work either, returning NULL.

Comment: You can do it without building the plot now using `layer_scales(p)$y$break_positions()`

Answer (score 2):

Check out `ggplot2::ggplot_build` - it can show you lots of details about the plot object.  You have to give it a plot object as input.  I usually like to `str()` the result of `ggplot_build` to see what all the different values it has are.

For example, I see that there is a `panel --> ranges --> y.major_source` vector that seems to be what you're looking for.  So to complete your example:

```
p <- ggplot() +
    geom_bar(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width), stat = 'identity')
pb <- ggplot_build(p)
str(p)
y.ticks <- pb$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.major_source
p + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = y.ticks), colour = 'white')
```

*Note that I moved the data argument from the main `ggplot` function to inside `geom_bar`, so that `geom_line` would not try to use the same dataset and throw errors when the number in iris is not a multiple of the number of lines we're drawing. Another option would be to pass a `data = data.frame()` argument to `geom_line`; I cannot comment on which one is a more correct solution, or if there's a nicer solution altogether.  But the gist of my code still holds :)*

Answer (score 2):

For ggplot 3.1.0 this worked for me:

```
ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.major_source
#[1]   0  50 100 150
```

Comment: In ggplot2 v3.3.0, this worked for me (but this also returns NAs in the vector for me): 

`ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y$breaks`

Comment: With ggplot2 v3.3.5 works too, but it returns one NA  at the end (something that I don't understand)

Answer (score -3):

for sure you can. Read the help file for the seq() function.

```
seq(from = min(), to = max(), len = 5)
```

and do something like this.

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
p + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = seq(from = min(), to = max(), len = 5)), colour = 'white')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even if this code would run, the sequence wouldn't necessarily correspond to the position of ggplot's grid lines.